# Yesod how to get record from inside hamlet

Tags: database, haskell, yesod, hamlet

The question: how do i get a record from the dataBase given a Maybe PersistInt64 (maybe primaryKey)
from inside hamlet

let's say i have a homepage. 
If a person visit my homepage who is logged in.
The person will be welcomed with his name and has the option to log out.
If a person visit my homepage who is not logged in.
The person will be asked to log in.

muid is a maybe PersistInt64
I want to get the user's record inside the hamlet code because
if someone visit the homepage who is not logged in it will cause a error
if we try to fetch a record with a nothing instead of a PersistInt64
so i only want to fetch a record by the userId aka (fromJust muid)
when muid is not nothing and that's in the code block of $maybe _ <- muid

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    muid <- maybeAuthId
    defaultLayout $ do
        [whamlet|
            <p>Welcome!
        $maybe _ <- muid
            <p>
                $with user <- fromJust (runDB $ get (fromJust muid)) 'does not work'        
                Welcome #{userIdent user}<br>
                <a href=@{AuthR LogoutR}>Logout
        $nothing
            <p>
                <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}>Go to the login page
|]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be (explanation below):

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    muid <- maybeAuthId
    m <- case muid of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just i  -> runDB $ get i

    defaultLayout $ do
        [whamlet|
            <p>Welcome!
        $maybe user <- m
            <p>        
                Welcome #{userIdent user}<br>
                <a href=@{AuthR LogoutR}>Logout
        $nothing
            <p>
                <a href=@{AuthR LoginR}>Go to the login page
|]
```

This way, we make a Maybe User out of m, and parse that in our template file. 
Notice the `$maybe user <- m`, this (roughly) translates to

```
case m of
    Just user -> do
        -- Do stuff with user, which is now of type User (and not Maybe User)
    Nothing -> do
        --Do stuff if m was nothing
```

So it's better not to wildcard your `$maybe _ <- muid`